# How to install MongoDBLibrary for Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I want to connect to Mongo DB using Robot Framework.

I have read in the following link that we have to pull the source code and install the library. [Robot FrameWork - MongoDB-Library](https://github.com/iPlantCollaborativeOpenSource/Robotframework-MongoDB-Library)

I installed the Library and it is installed in the location

```
D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MongoDBLibrary
```

When I add `'MongoDBLibrary'` library in the `RIDE` it showing in red (means library is not installed properly), 
when i ran the same using `eclipse + Maven project` i got the following error

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file 'D:\Robot_WorkSpace\robotFrameWork\src\test\robotframework\acceptance\MongoQuery.txt': Importing test library 'D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MongoDBLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named bson
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MongoDBLibrary\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from mongoquery import MongoQuery
  File "D:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\MongoDBLibrary\mongoquery.py", line 2, in <module>
    from bson.objectid import ObjectId
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\Users\akurasa\.m2\repository\org\robotframework\robotframework\3.0\Lib
  C:\Users\akurasa\.m2\repository\org\robotframework\robotframework\3.0\robotframework-3.0.jar\Lib
  __classpath__
  __pyclasspath__/
CLASSPATH:
  /D:/Sarada/eclipse/configuration/org.eclipse.osgi/bundles/789/1/.cp/jars/plexus-classworlds-2.4.jar
```

Please any one help me where i did wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you have installed PyMongo (or bson):

`pip install pymongo`

`pip install bson`  (don't know if still required then)

Comment: Hi helio, I have installed pymongo, after that no error came. Thanks for your help. Now I am trying to connect to mongo DB, the following steps followed. `Connect to mongoDB dbhost=172.20.31.236 dbPort=27017` this step is success, after that querying getting error authorization required error, please help me, how to authorize

Comment: Please mark my answer as accepted.
(The auth problem would certainly have an answer in documentation)

Comment: to connect mongo db how to pass username and password?